# Mongodb update nested array by key-value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I update nested array by list key value?

```
{
    "_id": "mainId",
    "events": [{
            "id": 1,
            "profile": 10,
        } {
            "id": 2,
            "profile": 10,
        } {
            "id": 3,
            "profile": 20,
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have a list to update:

```
var list = {id: 2, newval: 222}, {id: 3, newval: 333}
```

How can I do an update in one query? Or in MongoDB, it will be like a loop?

```
for({id, val} in list){
     update({_id: "mainId", events.$.id: id}, {setField: {events.$.profile: val}})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a copy of the events array, you could make the necessary updates in your code and then send the updated array to MongoDB in a single query.  Something like this

```
db.Test.updateOne({_id: "mainId"}, {$set: { "events": [{id: 1, profile: 222}, {id: 2, profile: 10}, {id: 3, profile: 333}] } } )
```

If you don't have a copy of the events array, you could do a bulk operation.  Something like

```
db.Test.bulkWrite(
  [

     { updateOne : {
        "filter": {_id: "mainId", "events.id": 1}, 
        "update": { $set: { "events.$.profile": 222 } }
     }
     },
     { updateOne : {
        "filter": {_id: "mainId", "events.id": 3}, 
        "update": { $set: { "events.$.profile": 333 }}
     }
     }
  ]
)
```

For more on bulkWrite, see the MongoDB docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulkwrite-methods

Comment: yes. i know only part of array. second example fits, thx. But mb can it do with new futures as pipline update in 4.2+ version ?!